# sed - What's the difference here?

Tags: sed

**test.txt** file contains:

```
AAAAA
BBBBB 
CCCCC
```

or in hex:

> 41 41 41 41 41 0A 42 42 42 42 42 0A 43 43 43 43  43 0A

If I run:

> sed s/A/B/g test.txt

it returns:

```
BBBBB
BBBBB
CCCCC
```

Likewise:

> sed 's/\x41/B/g' test.txt

returns:

```
BBBBB
BBBBB
CCCCC
```

but if I run:

> sed 's/\x0A/B/g' test.txt

it still returns:

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
```

Why?

Comment: I think he expects AAAAABBBBBBBCCCCC

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n

Comment: see the 2nd answer in this question - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters - it seems that sed reads a file line by line, not the whole file at once

Answer (score 2):

`sed` works on one line at a time. For each line of the file, `sed` puts it on pattern-space by removing the new line (`\n`) from the line and does some action. Once the action is done, it places the new line back to the line and prints it out by default and reads the next line into pattern-space (unless forced not to by using `-n` option). This continues until the end of file is reached.

For your attempt, when `sed` reads the first line, it has already removed the new line from the line, hence your substitution is basically a no-op. Once that is done, it puts the new line back to your first line, prints it and reads the second line into pattern space and continues.

To get your desired output, you will have to read the entire file in to pattern space, with each line separated by a new line character.

You can do so by saying:

```
$ sed ':a;N;s/\x0A/B/;ba' file
AAAAABBBBBBBCCCCC
```

- `:a` creates a label
- `N` appends the next line into pattern spaces separated by a new line so your pattern spaces no contains `line1\nline2`.
- `s/\x0A/B/` is removing the `\n` from your pattern space and replaces it with `B`.
- `ba` tells the `sed` to go back to label `:a` and repeat the process.
- In the second run `sed` again appends the next line in to pattern space. Now your pattern spaces looks like `line1Bline2\nline3`. When the substitution occurs, you are left with your desired output.